# How to Get Entity Display Name in a Plugin Running in the Context of a User Without Rights to ReadEntity and ReadRelationship?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

### Background

I have a custom C# plugin that disallows activation / deactivation of some entities for particular roles.  I used the `RetrieveEntityRequest` to get the EntityMetadata for the entity the plugin is executing for, and lookup the `DisplayCollectionName.LocalizedLabels.First().Label` to get the display name of the entity, and display it to the user in an error message:

> Access Denied yon't have rights to "My Custom Entity"

The call to `RetreieveEntityRequest` is wrapped in a try catch that eats any exception, and the logical name is displayed instead (i.e. new_mycustomentity).

### The Problem

When a user without Read rights to Entity or Relationship, executes the plugin, the logical name is being displayed (due to the user not having rights).

How do I show the display name of an entity, while keeping the plugin registered as "run in calling user's context" and not giving the user Read rights to Entity and Relationship?

Comment: If I understand correctly, if you remove all the privileges for that entity (means all empty circles inside a role) you can't get the entity logical name, right? what if inside your `deactivation` state you leave only a share permission set to user and all the other permissions to none? I think in this case you will be able to get the entity logical name but the user can do nothing (because he can share but he can't read the records)

Comment: @GuidoPreite `ReadEntity` and `ReadRelationship` are specific rights on the Customization Tab of the Security Roles page.  The role already has rights to read and write to "new_mycustomentity" (hence the activate/deactivate button is being displayed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create instance of service as SYSTEM user, and execute `RetrieveEntityRequest` to get label regardless of current user permissions

```
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(null);
```

Comment: Oh duh, it really is just that simple isn't it?

Comment: I believe so... Hope you won't ruin my world... ;)

Comment: Yep... Just did some further testing.  That's all that was required.